# Assign additional info to a class field in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class with some fields. For example:

```
class A(object):
    uri = text
    id = text
    name = text
```

Some of them are sortable, some filterable and some have a database column assigned. I want to assign this data to every field to be able to acquire these information dynamically in another part of code. However I cannot change the type of these fields as they are used by web framework.

In Java I would be able to apply annotation to every field and read data later using reflections.

In Python the only way of doing this that I see is to make additional private field that will contain a dictionary with needed data.

I'm looking for a solution that use some "Python magic" and is more elegant. Any ideas?

Comment: Note: That's not how you make an instance field in Python. Those are class fields; set `self.uri`, `self.id`, and `self.name` in the constructor to make instance fields.

Comment: What is the web framework, and what are the actual field classes? They probably have some useful methods to do this.

Comment: @user2357112: I understand the difference. Framework is using class fields to determine type of variable when validating instance fields.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: It's WSME. Classes of these fields are... types.

Comment: I'm not sure, whether you may change the class definition. If you do, you should take a look at the property function and define __get__ functions for the attributes in question. These __get__ functions could store the desired information e.g. in their docstrings.